# WP8 app with large signalr component only works on Emulator

Tags: azure, windows-phone-8, signalr

I have a `SignalR` enabled `Web API` server on `Azure`, and I have created a Windows Phone 8 client app that works perfectly well with the server on my `WP8 Emulator`.

After deploying to my Nokia Lumia 925 device, none of the components that demonstrate Server - Client push work.

Like, literally, nothing Signal R works on the app, but when I run it again on my `Emulator` everything works.

I just don't get what is going on.

I need help, please.

Thanks

**UPDATE**

The REST API and the SignalR powered streaming API are live on Azure.

Basically, I can make posts to the rest API, but then the Streaming API which is meant to broadcast that post to all connected clients including the originating client fails on the deployed device, but not on the emulator.

Comment: Looks a lot like a network issue. Have you tried connecting your phone to a wifi network?

Comment: I have updated the question, please have a look.

Comment: You haven't answered my question. On the device, are you using a Wifi connection or the phone's data connection? Can you try after connecting your phone to a Wifi network?

Comment: I was actually on a Wi-Fi network, however, after turning Wi-Fi off, it worked for a bit and then stopped on subsequent trials. Then turned Wi-Fi back on and all of a sudden it works, but also only for a bit. Now it works whenever it feels like. I can't even make any more test cases. All I know is that on the emulator, it works all the time. :'(

Answer (score 2):

Could be proxy/connection related.

On the emulator you could be using a debug/emulated version of your Azure Service in which case the WP8 client app can see it fine. You may want to make sure the WCF Service has actually been deployed to Azure it is accessible over the web and its not actually pointing to locahost.

Then once your sure of all that just make sure your phone's browser can see the services end-points on azure and the client app should see it fine.

Comment: The REST API and the SignalR powered streaming API are live on Azure.
Unless the proxy used when connecting to the rest api is different for that used when connecting to the SignalR streaming API, then I doubt that is the case. Basically, I can make post to the rest API, but then the Streaming API which is meant to broadcast to all clients including the originating client fails on the deployed device, but not on the emulator. This is what is happening to me.

Comment: I have had issues with proxy blocking me out in the past. Your sure that the WP8 app is not pointing to a local version of the windows azure services that runs in debug mode? Make sure the end points in the WP8 app are pointing to windows azure in the cloud, you can check these in the app.config, otherwise it is definitely some type of proxy I cant think of anything else.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe also try using Fiddler to see what network traffic is coming from your emulator and also the app once on-device.  Also check you're not trying to hit "localhost" once deployed to your device. See here for how to use Fiddler with WP8 emulator and devices: http://www.spikie.be/blog/post/2013/01/04/Windows-Phone-8-and-Fiddler.aspx

Comment: Updated the question's context.